# Custom comparator not sorting correctly

Tags: java, android, sorting

I created a custom comparator on my custom object.

What I want is to sort my items following those rules:

1. the 1st item in my ordered list should be the original list item with `ID == null` (I'm sure there is only one, or none, for each list to be sorted)
2. the 2nd item in my ordered list should be the original list item with `ID == emptyUUID` (an empty UUID, so all 0s; I'm also sure there is only one, or none, for each list to be sorted)
3. the remaining items will fill up the list sorted by `CODE`

This is what I tried:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Component f) {
    if (getID() == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (getID().equals(RuntimeHelper.emptyUUIDString)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (getCODE() == null || getCODE().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (f.getCODE() == null || f.getCODE().isEmpty()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return getCODE().compareToIgnoreCase(f.getCODE());
}
```

But what I get is:

- 1st --> a list of some objects sort by `CODE`
- 2nd --> in the middle of the list my object with `ID == null / emptyUUID`
- 3rd --> other items sort by `CODE`

What am I missing?

### Solution, thanks to Henry and Stephen

*I know it's still raw but it works, going to make it a bit looking better soon*

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Component f) {
    if (f.getID() == null && getID() == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (getID() == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (f.getID() == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (f.getID().equals(getID())) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (getID().equals(RuntimeHelper.emptyUUIDString)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (f.getID().equals(RuntimeHelper.emptyUUIDString)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (getCODE() == null || getCODE().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (f.getCODE() == null || f.getCODE().isEmpty()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return getCODE().compareToIgnoreCase(f.getCODE());
}
```

Comment: From the documentation: "The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. "

Comment: @Henry thanks, I solved starting from your comment. Didn't know that!

Comment: There's still a bug,  What if both `this` and `f` have a `null` CODE value?  Also, your spec doesn't say that `Component` objects with equal IDs are equal.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for commenting! I didn't specify it because `ID` are `UUID`s as string and it should not be possible to have duplicates. Also the `ID = null` should be unique since I add it manually just once. For those reasons if I find duplicates, the order doesn't matter in my case (and it should not appen at all) and for this reason I return 0 that should mean that they are equals. Both cases of same `ID` or both `ID null`, still same `ID`, should be considered as "they are equals", am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry ... my mistake on the bug.  I misread the code (it was ~1am) But I think I'm correct on the "specification flaw".  The spec *should* state that Component objects should be sorted by ID.  We should have to infer it.  (Because it can't be inferred logically from facts that are *stated* in your question or from your original code!)

Comment: @StephenC I don't know if I understood this correctly (sorry, my english is not perfect at all). You mean that I should add to my question the fact that I need to sort components by id? I specified in my first 3-4 rows how I wanted to sort them, maybe I mis-understood you

Comment: What I am saying is that those first 4 / 5 sentences *don't* actually say that.  The "1st --> item..." says how to deal with the case where ID is null.  The "2nd --> item..." says how to deal with the case where ID is EMPTYUUID.  Nothing says how to deal with the case where ID is some other UUID value.   A plausible interpretation is that you should *ignore* the ID field.  And this is reinforced by "3rd --> other items sort by CODE".

Comment: And please note, I'm not just being a pedant here.  When I first read your question, that is how I interpreted your requirements.   FWIW, this is not really an issue with your English.  One could state your requirements in a number of mathematical notations ... without any English at all.

Comment: (But I see that I wrote "We should have to infer it." when I should have said "We shouldn't have to infer it.".  That was my mistake.  Sorry.)

Comment: @StephenC oooh now I got it! Thanks a lot for making me notice that. Knowing the problem I didn't think at the other possible interpretations of my question. I edited my sorting spec, now they should be more unequivocable!  Let me know! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some problems:

```
if (getID() == null) {
    return -1;
}
```

The above violates the contract if `f.getID()` is also `null`.  In addition, if `f.getID()` is `null` an `this.getUID()` NOT `null`, then you should return +1 at this point

```
if (getID().equals(RuntimeHelper.emptyUUIDString)) {
    return -1;
}
```

Similar flaws to the previous case.

```
if (getCODE() == null || getCODE().isEmpty()) {
    return -1;
} else if (f.getCODE() == null || f.getCODE().isEmpty()) {
    return 1;
}
```

Similar flaws to the previous case ... when *both* codes are null or empty.

---

The above variously violate one or both of these invariants:

- `compare(a, a) == 0` for all `a != null`
- `compare(a, b) == -1` <=> `compare(b, a) == +1` for all `a != null` and `b != null`

Comment: True, I didn't know the rule that Henry posted and the explaination you gave me. I will add my fixed code in my question (even if not beautiful). Waiting the time to accept this :)

Comment: probably, but never say never ^^